# TextView doesn't pass click to parent

Tags: android

I have an ExpandableListView with a group header that shall expand and collapse when clicked. This works for clicks on an ImageView that is inside the list item and it works on directly clicking the item and so on but it doesn't work for a TextView in the list item.
I have to give the TextView a OnClickListener and catch the click separately. This is not nice especially because I don't have all data that I normally get in the OnGroupClickListener.

I read about making the TextView `clickable=true` and `focusable=false` but this didn't help. What else will I have to set or change to make the click go "through" the TextView to the base view?

Edit
**see my answer for the reason.**
Anyway I show how the GroupClickListener is set.
And of course clickable is set to true, not false.
In my activity that displays this list I do this

```
ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener groupClickListener = new ...() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
  if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
    parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
  else
    parent.expandGroup(groupPosition, true);
  return true;
  }
};
```

then assign this to the expandable listview.
`listView.setOnGroupClickListener(groupClickListener);`

Comment: TextViews on Android are not clickable or focusable by default. Are you sure it's the text view who is catching the click event? If so, it's probably because you made it clickable somewhere. Also, how do you set a listener on your parent view? Sharing some adapter code might help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty clear now as I found it.

I did set `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` what I found as advice because I sometimes experienced the TextView to show underlines as an indicator of spelling mistakes.
Probably this sets the view in focusable mode which captures the click.

I have to find out what's the deal with those underlines. Why only sometimes? Why at all? They are pretty stupid for an element that shall not accept any input but simply display static text.

But at least I found it and I hope this can help others to save some time.